# Spring Boot - Can A Web Application Use Its Own Rest Api

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

So I'm new to Spring Boot and am trying to get my head around how it works. But I can't find some of the answers I'm looking for online so was hoping somebody might be able to help me out.

1. My first question is, can a web application use its own rest api to
   manipulate data eg. get, post, put etc. or is the api just limited
   to use by other applications/websites etc. If this is the case how does a a web
   application manipulate it's data does it just use a seperate
   conventional controller?
2. My second question is, let's say I've a piece of code like this

   ```
   @GetMapping("/responsebody")
   @ResponseBody
   public UserAccount testingResponseBody(Principal principal) {
       if(principal != null) {
           UserAccount currentUser = userRepo.findByUserName(principal.getName());
           return currentUser;
       }else {
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

   A simple piece of code that returns a JSON for the currentUser. The
   thing that has me a little confused is why would someone want the
   current user JSON to be visible at the corresponding URL i.e
   localhost:8080/responsebody. I mean lets say the controller is accessed by an AJAX request. The data is only needed internally in the
   application. Why display it to the world at that URL. I feel like I'm missing something important. Is there a way to make certain controller methods only usable within the application to manipulate data without showing it at a URL.
3. Also if anyone knows of any really good resources where I can get
   these concepts to sink in it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys, hope I didn't make it too long.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you expose path then every apps can access to that path. If you want to use internal, you can restrict that path using security for example like "only apps that have authority 'INTERNAL_CLIENT' should only be access to that path"